# Android databinding generalisation issue

Tags: android, android-databinding

Not really a question but a hint to people who rely on the Android DataBinding library from Google.

So, I just wanted to adjust way of binding and notifying `view-models` by keeping them in parent `Activity` class. Basically, it looks like:

```
interface AbsViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    final int NO_ID = -1;
    int getVariableId();
    void start();
    void stop();
}

class abstract AbsBindingActivity<VB extends ViewDataBinding> extends Activity {
    private Map<Integer, AbsViewModel> mViewModels;
    private VB mBinding;

    public abstract getLayoutResource();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, getLayoutResource());
    }

    public VB getBinding() {
        return mBinding;
    }

    public <VM extends AbsViewModel> VM registerViewModel(VM viewModel) {
        int variableId = viewModel.getVariableId();
        if (variableId != AbsViewModel.NO_ID) {
            mBinding.setVariable(variableId, viewModel);
        }
        mViewModels.put(variableId, viewModel);
        return viewModel;
    }

    public  <VM extends AbsViewModel> VM unregisterViewModel(int variableId) {
        mBinding.setVariable(variableId, null);
        return (VM) mViewModels.remove(variableId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        for (AbsViewModel viewModel : mViewModels.values()) {
            viewModel.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    private void start() {
        for (AbsViewModel viewModel : mViewModels.values()) {
            viewModel.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        for (AbsViewModel viewModel : mViewModels.values()) {
            viewModel.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

But for some strange reason, I ended up with BR and DataBindings being not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally I've found a solution for it. For some mysterious reason without this method (even bodyless) databinding fails to generate BR class and actual bindings:

`public void setBinding(VB binding) { }`

So, I'm curious how many of you have faced with this issue and if you did what are the other ways to solve it.